# Random Forest by R package party overfits on random data

Tags: r, random-forest

I am working on Random Forest classification.

I found that cforest in "party" package usually performs better than "randomForest".
However, it seemed that cforest easily overfitted.

### A toy example

Here is a random data set that includes response of binary factor and 10 numerical variables generated from rnorm().

```
# Sorry for redundant preparation.
data <- data.frame(response=rnorm(100))
data$response <- factor(data$response < 0)
data <- cbind(data, matrix(rnorm(1000), ncol=10))
colnames(data)[-1] <- paste("V",1:10,sep="")
```

Perform cforest, employing unbiased parameter set (maybe recommended).

```
cf <- cforest(response ~ ., data=data, controls=cforest_unbiased())
table(predict(cf), data$response)
#       FALSE TRUE
# FALSE    45    7
# TRUE      6   42
```

Fairly good prediction performance on *meaningless* data.

On the other hand, randomForest goes honestly.

```
rf <- randomForest(response ~., data=data)
table(predict(rf),data$response)
#       FALSE TRUE
# FALSE    25   27
# TRUE     26   22
```

Where these differences come from?
I am afraid that I am using cforest in a wrong way.

Let me put some extra observations in cforest:

1. The number of variables did not much affect the result.
2. Variable importance values (computed by varimp(cf)) were rather low, compared to those using some realistic explanatory variables.
3. AUC of ROC curve was nearly 1.

I would appreciate your advices.

### Additional note

Some wondered why a training data set was applied to the predict().
I did not prepare any test data set because the prediction was done for OOB samples, which was not true for cforest.
*c.f.* http://www.stat.berkeley.edu/~breiman/RandomForests/cc_home.htm

Comment: Why are you evaluating your models using the data that trained them?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You cannot learn anything about the true performance of a classifier by studying its performance on the training set. Moreover, since there is no true pattern to find you can't really tell if it is worse to overfit like `cforest` did, or to guess randomly like `randomForest` did. All you can tell is that the two algorithms followed different strategies, but if you'd test them on new unseen data both would probably fail.

The **only** way to estimate the performance of a classifier is to test it on external data, that has not been part of the training, in a situation you do know there is a pattern to find.

Some comments:

1. The number of variables shouldn't matter if none contain any useful information.
2. Nice to see that the variable importance is lower for meaningless data than meaningful data. This could serve as a sanity check for the method, but probably not much more.
3. AUC (or any other performance measure) doesn't matter on the training set, since it is trivial to obtain perfect classification results.

Comment: Note that for regular `randomForest` the predict method returns the out-of-bag predictions, which, while perhaps not as good as using a completely different test set, it isn't really like returning the predictions on the actual training set either. This is not the default for cforest's predict method, I believe, but I think there is an OOB argument that lets you change that.

Comment: That was something that I should've known. Pity but I was presuming that cforest handled OOB estimation as randomForest did.

Answer (score 3):

The `predict` methods have different defaults for `cforest` and `randomForest` models, respectively. `party:::predict.RandomForest` gets you

```
function (object, OOB = FALSE, ...) 
    {
        RandomForest@predict(object, OOB = OOB, ...)
    }
```

so

```
table(predict(cf), data$response)
```

gets me

```
        FALSE TRUE
  FALSE    45   13
  TRUE      7   35
```

whereas

```
table(predict(cf, OOB=TRUE), data$response)
```

gets me

```
        FALSE TRUE
  FALSE    31   24
  TRUE     21   24
```

which is a respectably dismal result.

Comment: Just a be aware that although the OOB error may be able to act as a poor mans repeated holdout test, it is probably better to make a real one (since the models in the real test will be more similar to the final model you will proceed to fit on all data).

Comment: @Backlin agreed. OOB shouldn't be used as a substitute for good practice.

Comment: Thanks for exactly what I overlooked (OOB arg). However, I thought OOB estimation was natural for RF, as the use of external data set would raise a need for cross validation.

Comment: In my book having a large external dataset is the best way to estimate performance. If you don't have a lot of data, you can do repeated holdout or (repeated) cross validate to make better use of the limited data you do have. The OOB error is a neat idea, and probably give you similar results to holdout or CV, but I am not entirely sure how it behaves and prefer to stick with what I know works.